# Cross-platform, Command line utilities to convert PDF, DOC and DOCX to text

Tags: linux

I am making a text search engine. I need to first convert binary documents to text. I want to go with cross-platform (we develop both on windows and linux) command line (so that I can get the output via python subprocess). What are the choices for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's *pdftotext* for PDFs and *antiword* for DOC (not sure about DOCX). Both free software for command line. Used both on Linux before, worked fairly well.

Sphider, a free search engine, uses *pdftotext* and *catdoc*. *catdoc* I've used as well, worked fine as well.

For DOC files there's also *wv* and *abiword* (*abiword* is a GUI but also has a command line interface). Haven't been able to test these out, though.

One tip for DOCX:

http://www.livedocx.com/

I have used this to convert DOC to PDF before, was quite good. Perhaps it supports TXT as well, or you could use *pdftotext*. LiveDocX also can be accessed via a SOAP web service

PS: there's also `pdftohtml`, `pdftk` command-line tools and then the suite/s `LibreOffice`, `OpenOffice` which can take DOCX and natively convert/save everything to text. Didn't try LibreOffice and OpenOffice from command-line, though...

Answer (score -1):

One supplement for pdf to text, i know another open source: [PDFLib tool](http://www.pdflib.com/). this library can convert whole pdf page to text with the page layout. and it supports multiple languages(all the ascii language), such as english, french, latin, besides, the CJK language is also supported, so it's very useful for your text search engine. and i find a online [pdf to text](http://www.online-code.net/pdf-to-word.html) tool using PDFLib, so you can make a performance of the PDFlib.